# How to get rows with a combination of partial and complete string match in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to get rows that contains exact column value `cat` and `lion` and a column value containing `saurus`

For exact match I know this

```
# Get indexes where column has cat and lion
indexNames = df[(df['start'] != 'cat') & (df['end'] != 'lion')].index
# Delete these row indexes from dataFrame
df = df.drop(indexNames)
```

For partial string match I do

```
// look for rows that contain column values consisting of saurus
df = df[df['type'].str.contains('saurus')]
```

How do I combine the above two to get a combination of exact matches and partial matches?

**Note:** I am looking for exact rows that meets the above criteria

```
cat lion dinosaurus

cat lion tyrannosaurus
```

And not

```
bobcat lion   dinosaurus
cat    molion tyrannosaurus
```

Comment: What do you mean by a combination? Please add input and expected output.

Comment: @DaniMesejo added a note. Please check now.

Comment: If you need to keep them, why is the first code dropping the rows?

Comment: I'm confused where is the lion in all this? As I said, better if you explain with full dummny examples covering all cases,

Comment: @DaniMesejo I am so sorry. I was switching between two different code so by mistake added wrong examples. Sorry about that.

Comment: @SouvikRay No need to be sorry, just please add your examples so people can easily help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm always leery about using `drop`. There is nothing really wrong with it, but as often in Python I find it easier to manage when *retaining* what you want instead of dropping it (e.g.: `[k for k in lst if wanted(k)]`, same for `dicts`, etc.)

So, for your case, how about:

```
mask = (df['start'] == 'cat') & (df['end'] == 'lion') & df['type'].str.contains('saurus')
df = df[mask]
```